# PHP request is not verifying if password is correct before continuing on HTML button

Tags: php, html

I'm not sure what to do here..
The PHP post request (request.php) just continues to next page after clicking the button (correct.html) even if I don't type anything in the input.
I'd want it to verify that the password is correct, if so = continue to correct.html, else alert user.

PHP code:

```
<?php 
$pass = $_POST['password'];

if ($pass == "password")
{
   include "correct.html";
}

else
{
   echo "Password incorrect";
}
?>
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="input-container">
    <input class="input-field" type="password" placeholder="Your passphrase" /><br>
    <i class="fa fa-user icon"></i>
</div><br>

<div id=continue>
    <form action="request.php" method="post">
     <button class="button" name="password" value="password" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>Confirm</span></button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Value of button is `value="password"`, so `$_POST['password']` is `"password"` and `"password"` == `"password"`, everything works as expected. And btw - there's __no__ `input` in the provided html form.

Comment: Well, it just includes the correct.html page whatever I type, must it be an input for the verification to work? It's button, because It messed up the CSS when I change to input.

Comment: What input? I don't see __any__ input in the provided form. Button __is not__ input.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just realized you meant the input box. I've added it to the code.

Comment: `input` box is not in the `form`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You should first add name attribute value for input type password or
>   button like below

```
<div id=continue>
        <form action="request.php" method="post">
            <input class="input-field" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Your passphrase" />
            <button class="button" name="submit" value="submit" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>Confirm</span></button>
        </form>
</div>
```

> After your php code should be like this

```
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    if ($pass == "password")
    {
       include "correct.html";
    }

    else
    {
       echo "Password incorrect";
    }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. So basically, submit in php is either name or value of the button?

Comment: submit is the name of the button.

Comment: @u_mulder process are same that's why i used your markup if you want to remove i will do this.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about [Form submissions in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php). In this particular instance your form isnt submitted as button need submit attribute, i.e. `<button type="submit"`.

Also, to debug the post data, you can use `var_dump($_POST); die();`.

Comment: `type="submit"` is the __default__ type of a button.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what your `form` must be:

```
<div id=continue>
    <form action="request.php" method="post">
        <!-- Note that input and button are under the SAME <form> -->
        <input class="input-field" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Your passphrase" />
        <!-- Note `name` attributes of `button` and `input`  -->
        <button class="button" name="button" value="submit" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>Confirm</span></button>
    </form>
</div>
```

On server:

```
<?php

// for debugging purposes, remove when you want
print_r($_POST);

// as 'password' is now NAME of INPUT, `$pass` stores the value from the INPUT
$pass = $_POST['password'];

if ($pass == "password")
{
   include "correct.html";
}

else
{
   echo "Password incorrect";
}
```